# windows 10 - I have the "Create a Windows 7 or 8 version install disk" but there's a problem

Tags: mac, bootcamp, high-sierra

I followed instructions in this video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gh667JSvymU showing me how to install Windows on my Mac and showed me how to get the "Create a Windows 7 or 8 version install disk" option. But, when I check it and continue in Bootcamp, it's showing me "There is no USB drive connected to the system. Please insert a USB drive to continue". I don't have a USB Drive and I already have the ISO image thing installed on my Mac. Here is what it shows:
[image]

Beneath the option "Create a Windows 7 or 8 version install disk", it says that I can use the ISO image downloaded from Microsoft but it always says that I need a USB drive. Can someone help me, I have been watching videos and researching on google for an hour but I cant find anything.

Comment: Can't you just use the last option?

Comment: jiiiiiiiwooooooooo: You are not reading the message correctly. The Boot Camp Assistant wants  to copy the files from the Windows ISO image to a USB flash drive.